# In GeoWebCache is there a way to disable the geowebcache.xml backups? (.bak)

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I have a very large geowebcache.xml file that is edited constantly. Every time the system makes a change to geowebcache.xml via the REST API GWC creates a backup of the geowebcache.xml file. These backups are taking up massive amounts of space each day and aren't being rotated by GWC.

I've checked the code and it seems it's only supposed to keep 10 backups, but that isn't happening. Is there any configuration setting to disable these backups?

The alternative is just to create a cron-job to periodically remove them I suppose. P.S we're using standalone GWC 1.8.

Comment: If the code is supposed to take care of that but it doesn't then it is probably a bug.

Comment: You did not mention what code you checked but I believe that it starts from https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache/blob/master/geowebcache/core/src/main/java/org/geowebcache/config/XMLConfiguration.java#L474.